# React Native : How to browse an array with many children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to browse an array that has many children, in one of my screen, in order to make a indented list, like this: 
1. Some item
  1.1. Some item 
     1.1.1. Some item
  1.2. Some item

One method that I found is to create an array, with objects, like this:

```
names: [
  {
    id: 0,
    level: 1,
    name: "Football",
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        level: 2,
        name: "Shoes",
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            level: 3,
            name: "Shoes 1"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            level: 3,
            name: "Shoes 2"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            level: 3,
            name: "Shoes 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I've already tried to browse this array, using `map`:

```
this.state.names.map((item, index) => (
  <TouchableOpacity>
    key={item.id}
    style={styles.container}
    onPress={() => this.alertItemName(item)}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
));
```

But, this kind of method browses only the first item, that is at level 1.

I don't know if I'm using the right component and the right method to do it. I've also looked at the `FlatList` component, but I had the same problem.

Comment: You need to use recursion. Check each child before displaying it, and if it's an array, turn it into a list as well, etc. You should probably do this outside the `render` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something recursive like this :

```
renderItems = items => (
  items.map((item, index) => this.renderItem(item, index));
);

renderItem = (item, index) => (
  <Component key={index}>
    // Do something with your item,
    // then call renderItems() again if there's a children array.
    {item.children && this.renderItems(item.children)}
  </Component>
);
```

then in your `render()` function you'll use it like that :

```
return this.renderItems(this.state.names);
```

**Simple working example :**

```js
const names = [
  {
    id: 0,
    level: 1,
    name: "Football",
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        level: 2,
        name: "Shoes",
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            level: 3,
            name: "Shoes 1"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            level: 3,
            name: "Shoes 2"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            level: 3,
            name: "Shoes 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  renderItems(items) {
    return <ul>{items.map((item, index) => this.renderItem(item, index))}</ul>;
  }

  renderItem(item, index) {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        {item.name}
        {item.children && this.renderItems(item.children)}
      </li>
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    return this.renderItems(names);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a lot for your help! In React Native, we can't use <ul>, <li>, right ?

Comment: Right, that's html :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map in the map

```
this.state.names.map((lev1,index) => {
   return (
       <View>
          <Text>{lev1.name}</Text>
          {lev1.children && lev1.children.map(lev2 => {
             //... your code
          }
       </View>
   )
}
```

Comment: That will raise an error when `children` is undefined